# Editable SHAP package gives - AttributeError: module 'shap' has no attribute 'DeepExplainer'

Tags: python, package, shap

I am trying to customise some code in the SHAP package to suit my needs. I am trying to apply it to a time-series forecasting model, so I cloned the package from github to my directory. From this, I made a fresh conda environment, installed all the packages I need (using pip), as well as SHAP. SHAP was installed with the `-e` prefix to ensure it was editable. I have added this environment as a kernel for jupyter notebook, as I am working in jupyterlab.
I can import the package without issue, but when I try to do anything with it, it gives me an attribute error:
 `AttributeError: module 'shap' has no attribute 'DeepExplainer'`
Similarly, when trying to print the version it gives the same:
 `AttributeError: module 'shap' has no attribute '__version__'`

When I first had the package installed normally (not `-e`), the package itself worked fine, but gave other problems due to my model format.

I have tried making a fully fresh conda environment to ensure there are no leftovers from a previous install, but this didn't help.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!